# Dataprep - Scheduling Jobs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

To anyone on the Dataprep beta, is it possible to schedule jobs being run? If so, is it the cron service via the app engine? I can't quite follow the cron for app engine instructions but want to make sure it's not a dead end before I try

Thanks

Comment: what's the point of scheduling job in dataprep? You cant replace the source dataset without accessing dataprep over GUI, right?

Comment: lol bit late on this but the datasource can read from bigquery or google cloud so the source can update easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in there now, with the possibility to add multiple schedules (ie daily, weekly, etc).

[image]